# Install hadoop on ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, bigdata

Hi i am new to Big Data concept. I have installed Hbase0.98-hadoop2. Does it mean that hadoop 2 has also been installed on my machine along with HBase? If yes then how can I run hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about Ubuntu packages. After the installation, you can do one quick experiment. In the shell, just type (incomplete command):

```
$ hadoop
```

If it tells you `command not found: hadoop`, then no, you don't have Hadoop installed.

Comment: Yeah it says command not found. Actually first I installed hbase0.98-hadoop2. But now I want to move my application data to hdfs using storm. So can you please mention the installation steps. Like what things I should install. I have installed storm. Do i have to install hadoop only now?

Comment: @Mr37037 Are you aware of that your question now is huge?

Comment: Yeah sorry for that I dont want installation steps. I just want to know the things i need to install.

Comment: @Mr37037 Sorry, I don't know your environment and your requirements. You asked a question and I answered it. Can't do more.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link for hadoop installation -
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: You might want to summarize it here; if the page you're linking ever gets moved/removed/otherwise rendered inaccessible, your answer gets left hanging.